# How to convert list of objects to list of map

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a Day class and a list of Day objects, I need to convert to a list from map of these objects.

```
class Day{
    double open;
    double high;
    double low;
    double close;
    double volumeTo;

    Day({this.open, this.high, this.low, this.close, this.volumeTo});
}

List historical = [
    new Day(open: 42.6, high: 53.9, low: 39.5, close:56.00, volumeTo: 5000.0),
    new Day(open: 42.6, high: 53.9, low: 39.5, close:56.00, volumeTo: 5000.0),
    new Day(open: 42.6, high: 53.9, low: 39.5, close:56.00, volumeTo: 5000.0),
    new Day(open: 42.6, high: 53.9, low: 39.5, close:56.00, volumeTo: 5000.0),
];
```

Finally i need for example like this:

```
List sampleData = [
    {"open":42.6, "high":53.9, "low":39.5, "close":56.00, "volumeto":5000.0},
    {"open":42.6, "high":53.9, "low":39.5, "close":56.00, "volumeto":5000.0},
    {"open":42.6, "high":53.9, "low":39.5, "close":56.00, "volumeto":5000.0},
    {"open":42.6, "high":53.9, "low":39.5, "close":56.00, "volumeto":5000.0},
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using android studio, you can install a pluging to help generate toMap() and fromMap() codes. The name of the plugin is **Dart Data Class**

After installing the plugin, generate the helper function like this

```
class Day{
  double open;
  double high;
  double low;
  double close;
  double volumeTo;

  Day({this.open, this.high, this.low, this.close, this.volumeTo});

  factory Day.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return new Day(
      open: map['open'] as double,
      high: map['high'] as double,
      low: map['low'] as double,
      close: map['close'] as double,
      volumeTo: map['volumeTo'] as double,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    // ignore: unnecessary_cast
    return {
      'open': this.open,
      'high': this.high,
      'low': this.low,
      'close': this.close,
      'volumeTo': this.volumeTo,
    } as Map<String, dynamic>;
  }
}

// this helper method helps convert to a list of Map
dynamic getListMap(List<dynamic> items) {
  if (items == null) {
    return null;
  }
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> dayItems = [];
  items.forEach((element) {
    dayItems.add(element.toMap());
  });
  return dayItems;
}
```

and call the function like this

```
void somthoing(){
 var listOfMap = getListMap(historical);
}
```

Comment: There's a similar plug-in for VSCode.

Comment: Great then.. I'm not using VSCode so I didn't know. But Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Using the [map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) method, like this:

```
final sampleData = historical.map((h) => {"open": h.open, "high": h.high, "low": h.low, "close": h.close, "volumeTo": h.volumeTo}).toList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Day().historical.map((e)=>{<- do your conversion here ->}).toList();
```